# Overlapping Background Image with Displayed Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #img1:hover{
            opacity:0.6;
        }
        .modal{
            position:fixed;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
            padding-top:100px;
            opacity:.95;
            display:none;
            z-index:1;
        }
        .close{
            float:right;
            padding:20px 30px;
            font-family:Arial;
            font-size:30px;
            color:gray;
        }
        .close:hover{
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        .modal-image{
            width:100%;
            max-width:800px;
            opacity:1;
            display:block;
            margin:auto;
            animation-name:imageTransform;
            animation-duration:0.8s;
        }
        @keyframes imageTransform{
            from{transform:scale(0);}
            to{transform:scale(1);}
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="img1"src="image.jpg" onclick="myDisplay()" width="400px" height="300px"/>
    <div class="modal">
        <span class="close">X</span>
        <img class="modal-image" id="img2"/>
    </div>
    <script>
        var v = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0];
        var i = document.getElementById('img1');
        var s = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];
        var k = document.getElementById('img2');
        function myDisplay()
        {
            v.style.display = "block";
            k.src = i.src;
        }
        s.onclick = function close()
        {
            v.style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Every thing is working fine except the image in background is interfering the image which is displayed which I don't want.I have checked with opacity=1, but it hides everything at the back. Please Help.

Comment: You can use variable names with more than one letter.

Comment: Yes. But here that's not an issue.

Comment: You don't have any CSS background-image properties anywhere, and from what you posted, it's not apparent which of the img elements is supposed to be the background image. It's also hard to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This is something called as Modal Images. @TheThirdMan

Comment: The scene is like this. There is an image. If we click this image it will be displayed as full screen image.

Comment: I posted a JSFiddle here with your code https://jsfiddle.net/86wx9w7f/ Can you explain what it should be doing that it isn't doing?

Comment: Yes Sure. The image when clicked get displays with some animation. You can observe that the image you clicked and the image that is displayed is bit overlapped and this overlapping is clearly visible. @grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the css for `.modal` class you have

```
 opacity:0.95;
```

the element with `.modal-image` class is a child of the element with `.modal` class, and so it inherits this opacity. Change the opacity of .modal to 1, and you won't see one object behind the other.

Comment: Isn't there any way to change opacity of just the child element? @grateful

Comment: You want the black background with some transparency, but the image with no transparency?

Comment: Yes I need the same.

Comment: `.modal { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.95); }`?

Comment: Yes. It did work. I needed to remove opacity property which was mentioned separately. Thank You. @grateful